# iOS application with center panel with revealable side panels : JASidePanels

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I am using [JASidePanels](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels) to have the same layout as Facebook but there is some limitation and I want you to help me to :

- Add a right button in the navigation controller of the center view controller
- Change the center View to a different view after a button press in a different view controller
- From left or right side tell the center view controller to push a view
- From left or right side go to a view inside tabbar view controller

here is my implementation inside MainAppDelegate :

```
/* tabbar views with their navigation controller */
SearchViewController *searchViewController = [[SearchViewController alloc]
   initWithNibName:@"SearchViewController" bundle:nil];
self.searchNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
initWithRootViewController:searchViewController];

MainViewController *mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc]
 initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
self.mainNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];

  /* uiviewcontroller for our left side view */
SideMenuViewController *sideMenuViewController=[[SideMenuViewController alloc]
initWithNibName:@"SideMenuViewController" bundle:nil];

  /* the center view of the side panel */
self.mainSidePanelviewController = [[JASidePanelController alloc] init];
self.mainSidePanelviewController.shouldDelegateAutorotateToVisiblePanel = NO;

   /* set the properties of JASidePanel*/

self.mainSidePanelviewController.leftPanel = sideMenuViewController ;
self.mainSidePanelviewController.centerPanel =  self.mainNavController;


[self.mainSidePanelviewController.centerPanel.navigationController
 setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];


NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
 self.mainSidePanelviewController,self.searchNavController ,nil];

[self.tabController setViewControllers:controllers];

// the tab bar is our root view
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

if there is a better open source project that allow me to do what I want to do , just give me the link

Comment: If you can tell me how to access the uinavigationbar of the side panels, because I need to add a right button

Comment: Did you finally solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Just add your own button (in viewDidLoad for example) and assign a selector to show the right panel:

`UIBarButtonItem *rightbutton = [UIBarButtonItem barItemWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rightIcon.png"] hightlightImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rightIcon.png"] target:self action:@selector(slideInRightHandView:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightbutton;`

Answer (score 0):

1. Import the interface header file

   #import "UIViewController+JASidePanel.h"
2. In the ViewController you want to add right button. Add the following code to viewDidLoad method.

   ```
   if (!self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem) {
       UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rightButtonImage.png"];
       CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
       UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];
       [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [button addTarget:self.sidePanelController action:@selector(toggleRightPanel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];  }
   ```

You can use any UIButton to create rightBarButtonItem.