# How to implement JASidePanel with interchangeable center panel?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an app that uses the JASidePanel to show a facebook like side menu. It's working great and I can show my left and right panels. But I need the left and right panels to be generic, i.e. if I segue from the current center panel view controller to a new one, say a details view controller, I need to still be able to show my left and right panels.

Consider this scenario with a MainVC and a DetailVC

Scene 1:

```
[left]-[center]-[right]
          |
       [MainVC]
```

Scene 2: upon going to next view controller

```
       [MainVC]

[left]-[center]-[right]
          |
      [DetailVC]
```

Scene 3: upon going to another view controller

```
       [MainVC]
      [DetailVC]

[left]-[center]-[right]
          |
    [MoreDetailVC]
```

The DetailVC is pushed and is "laid on top" of the center panel while the MainVC is still there somewhere on the stack. I need the segues and the push because

1. I use storyboard
2. In other view controllers I call popToRootViewController and I need the MainVC to be the rootViewController

I have tried performing a segue from the MainVC to DetailVC

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier...];
```

and at the DetailVC I set the center panel to self like so:

```
//in view will appear
sidePanelViewController.centerPanel = self;
```

This produces a black screen for my app. I think this happens because the setter method of the center panel also loads the view controller but the view has already been loaded so it kinda like doubles the segue. 
If I remove the line above, the detailVC shows up good, but I can't access the left and right panels.

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736418/jasidepanels-how-to-navigate-to-different-center-views), 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634684/ios-jasidepanels-make-the-uinavigationcontroller-the-centerviewcontroller) and 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820455/ios-application-with-center-panel-with-revealable-side-panels-jasidepanels) but 
answers have not been given.
I'm thinking this might not be possible with JASidePanel and I'm considering on using other resources.

**EDIT:**
Instead of performing segue at the MainVC, I tried setting the center panel there directly like so:

```
sidePanelViewController.centerPanel = [self.storyboard instantiateVCWithIdentifier:@"detailVC"];
```

And it works, it goes to the DetailVC not via segue so there's no animation but the left and right panels can be accessed. The problem is I cannot return to mainVC using popToRootViewController.
(I need to return to the mainVC in an instant using popToRootViewController because there can be many transitions, its like a home button)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of performing a segue to the next center view controller, I deleted all segues and used:

```
sidePanelViewController.centerPanel = 
    [self.storyboard instantiateVCWithIdentifier:@"detailVC"];
```

This changes the center panel but with no push animation, so that's kinda sad. I then saved a pointer of the main view controller somewhere accessible global, let's say the App Delegate. Then when I pressed the home button, I return home like so:

```
sidePanelViewController.centerPanel = appDelegate.mainViewControllerPointer;
```

This returns me to the main view controller in the state that I left it. If I instantiave a new view controller with the [self.storyboard instantiate...] a main view controller is put as center panel without some form data I left it with and that is not what I want